# UIAppearance - reload

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I would like to add my custom shadow under UINavigationBar. Everything works perfectly when application has been initialize, but problem appears when I want to hide this shadow on button action. How to reload/refresh UINavigationBar (same but with nil/empty image, does not work any reaction - project is using storyboard).

Edit: I was trying to setNeedsDisplay, same not working

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shadow"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:nil];
```